# How to use Genymotion with Socks5 Proxy

Tags: android, macos, virtualbox, genymotion, socks

I have been trying to get Genymotion to work with a Socks5 proxy, but everytime I try to load a Genymotion instance with a proxy, I just get a blank screen. I'm running on Mac OS High Sierra, and I'm using ProxyCap for my Socks5. I know that Genymotion uses Virtual Box to connect, but I can't figure out how to configure everything to get it to work. I've been searching on forums all over, but nothing has helped. If anyone can offer any help, that would be awesome.

Comment: Have you found an answer for this?